# Does did you had is ok to say?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say:

"Did you already had the opportunity to do something?"

or I should use:

"Did you already get the opportunity to do something?"

instead.

Is the already word well positioned? Is it redundant?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Had" is not the appropriate tense to use in this case: you must use "have". The grammatically correct form of your sentence would be "Did you already have the opportunity to do something?"

Otherwise, your sentence is just fine.

By the way:

Slightly different phrasing will give you a slightly different meaning. For example, the sentence as it is means plainly "Is it the case that you got the chance to do something before something else occurred / before the current moment?" (Eg, "Did you already have the chance to speak to Thomas?")

On the other hand, you could say "Had you already had/gotten the opportunity to do something?" meaning "Did you, at that point in the past, get the chance to do something before something else occurred?" (Eg, "In 1999, had you already gotten the opportunity to visit Spain prior to moving to Barcelona?")

If you say "Have you already had/gotten the opportunity to do something?" you mean "Is it the case that, as of the current moment, you have gotten the chance to do something?" (Eg, "Have you already gotten the chance to eat breakfast today?")

The first is the most general in terms of time; the second refers to the past; the third refers specifically to the current moment.

These nuances are so subtle, however, that an error will not cause confusion and may even go unnoticed.